# Commands behaving differently in script vs shell

Tags: powershell, csv

I've got two powershell functions in a file.  The first one (`Get-ImapAttachments`) connects using the NetCmdlets IMAP cmdlets, downloads all *.csv attachments from any messages in the INBOX, and then moves the messages to another folder to keep the INBOX clean.  I got this function from the NetCmdlets site, and tweaked it slightly for my needs.  On it's own, it works the way I need it to.

I've written a second function (`Import-D2LData`) to process the CSV file.  It's a badly formatted CSV file, complete with a report title on the first line, and the column headings are repeated every 23 lines or so.  Since `Import-Csv` isn't quite as flexible as I need, I use a combination of `get-content` and `select-object -skip 1` to start off the import, and basically build a long string to pass to `ConvertFrom-Csv`.  If I run that function manually, it currently works the way I need it to, also.

The problem arises when I run it in the .ps1 file I've got them in.  The first function fires off just fine, and the second one seems to.  The `ConvertFrom-Csv` fails and I end up with a bunch of empty lines of output.  The real strangeness is, I can use the `.` command to source the .ps1 file, and run the last 7 lines of the script (starting with the call to `Get-ImapAttachments`), and I get the expected results.

I'm sure I'm doing something pretty braindead, but after staring at the code for a couple of hours, I'm just not seeing it at this point...

```
# Needed for the IMAP Stuff
Add-PSSnapin -Name NetCmdlets -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function Get-ImapAttachments {
    param(
        [string] $server,
        [string] $user,
        [string] $password,
        [string] $downloadDir="c:\temp\attachments",
        [string] $folder = "INBOX"
    )

    $destFolder = "$folder.Processed"

    $imapConnection = Connect-Imap -server $server -user $user -password $password

    $m_messages  = Get-Imap -connection $imapConnection -folder $folder

    foreach($msg in $m_messages)
    {
       if($msg.ContentType.StartsWith("multipart")) #A MIME message with multiple parts
       {
          for($i=0;$i -lt $msg.PartCount;$i++)
          {
             if($msg.PartFileName[$i] -like "*.csv" ) #There is a CSV attachment
             {
                $localFile = $downloadDir + "\" + $msg.PartFileName[$i]
                if( Test-Path -Path $localFile ) {
                    Remove-Item $localFile -Force
                }
                Get-Imap -connection $imapConnection -folder $folder -view $msg.Id -localfile $localFile -part $msg.PartId[$i]
                Move-Imap -Connection $imapConnection -folder $folder -Message $msg.Id -Destination $destFolder

             }
          }
       }
    }
    Disconnect-IMAP -Connection $imapConnection
}

function Import-D2LData {
    param(
        [string] $CsvFile
    )

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $CsvFile    
    $file = get-content $CsvFile | Select-Object -Skip 1
    $head = $file[0].Split(',')
    $data = "$head`n"
    foreach ( $line in $file ) {
        if( $line -ne $file[0] ) {
            $data += "$line`n"
        }
    }
    $csv = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $head


    $csv
}

Get-ImapAttachments -server imap.contoso.com -user sa_mailbox -password 'password'

$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\attachments" -Filter "*.csv"

foreach( $file in $csvFiles ) {
    Import-D2LData -CsvFile $file.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it wasn't pretty, but I ended up breaking the functions into two different scripts.  When that wasn't enough, I ran the first script in it's own PowerShell instance, which seemed to isolate the runspaces enough to allow both functions to operate properly:

```
$BasePath = 'Z:\scripts\Import-Data'

powershell.exe -NoProfile -command "& '$BasePath\fetch-attachments.ps1'"
& "$BasePath\process-attachments.ps1"
```

Not exactly an elegant solution, but it got me past the issues I was having...